# Dataframe with 3 columns, remove all duplicate rows where value in column 1 and column 2 is identical

Tags: r, dplyr

So far, I have the following code in R (column names etc changed to generic things):

```
# Sort the dataset by "col_x" and "col_z" in descending order
sorted_df <- original_df[order(sorted_df$col_x, -original_df$col_z), ]

# Select only the desired columns
selected_columns <- c("col_x", "col_y", "col_z")
sorted_df <- sorted_df[selected_columns]

# Topt 5 highest values by group
top_5_words <- sorted_df %>%                                     
  arrange(desc(col_z)) %>% 
  group_by(col_a) %>%
  slice(1:5)
```

So I have a dataframe, let's call it sorted_df with 3 columns col_x, col_y, and col_z and 1200 rows, sorted by the highest values in col_z.

col_x contains six unique strings (let's call them A, B, C, D, E and F).
col_y contains 800 unique strings (things like, let's say, "alphabet", "noodle", "whatever").
col_z contains 1200 unique floats (e.g. 0.1234, 0.9876 etc.).

My goal is to select the 5 rows with the highest values in col_z, by group (col_x). So for example for A, there should be 5 rows for A, with 5 unique strings in col_y, and the values in col_z.

Problem is, there are duplicate values in col_x and col_y that have different values in col_z.
So what I'm currently getting is something like: row 1: A, Banana, 0.998. row 2: A, Banana, 0.997. row 3: A, Banana, 0.991 (...) B, Apple, 0.841. B, Apple, 0.811 etc.

How do I remove all values that are duplicated in col_x and col_y, but not col_z, so that I get the 5 highest unique values by row (no duplicates)?

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here, please provide some test data and the output you expect from that test data.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve your question. If you only want the top rows of col_z based on col_a, only group by col_a. If you want to see the top rows of col_z based on col_a and col_b (col_a would values would be repeated since there are only 6 unique values in the dataset) then group by both col_a and col_b.

```
sorted_df %>% 
group_by(col_a) %>% 
slice_max(order_by = col_z, n = 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
```

From your description your data looks something like this(?):

```r
sorted_df <-
  tibble(
    col_x = sample(LETTERS[1:6], 1200, replace = TRUE),
    col_y = sample(c("alphabet", "noodle", "whatever", "and", "some", "more"), 1200, replace = TRUE),
    col_z = rnorm(1200)
  )
sorted_df
#> # A tibble: 1,200 × 3
#>    col_x col_y     col_z
#>    <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
#>  1 C     alphabet  0.142
#>  2 D     and      -0.909
#>  3 B     alphabet  0.819
#>  4 C     alphabet -1.37 
#>  5 A     whatever -0.650
#>  6 C     alphabet  0.446
#>  7 E     whatever  0.127
#>  8 B     and      -0.896
#>  9 F     and      -0.210
#> 10 E     alphabet  0.684
#> # ℹ 1,190 more rows
```

To achieve what you describe we first filter down so that we only
have the highest values for `col_z` for all combinations of `col_x` and `col_y`.
Next we `slice_max()` to the top 5 `col_z` values within groups of `col_x`

```r
sorted_df |> 
  group_by(col_x, col_y) |>  
  slice_max(order_by = col_z, n = 1) |> 
  group_by(col_x) |> 
  slice_max(order_by = col_z, n = 5) |> 
  arrange(col_x, col_z)
#> # A tibble: 30 × 3
#> # Groups:   col_x [6]
#>    col_x col_y    col_z
#>    <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
#>  1 A     some      1.64
#>  2 A     and       1.67
#>  3 A     whatever  2.13
#>  4 A     alphabet  2.20
#>  5 A     noodle    2.48
#>  6 B     and       1.98
#>  7 B     more      2.02
#>  8 B     some      2.21
#>  9 B     alphabet  2.64
#> 10 B     noodle    3.04
#> # ℹ 20 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a fourth column like this that is just the concatenation of the first and second columns, and add a marker for the columns that I want to delete later:

```
df$extra_col <- paste0(df$col1, df$col2)
df$count <- 0 #Will have the same number of rows as the rest of the dataset
```

To get the rows that you need to delete, you need to know how many rows above each row has an identical fourth column.

```
for (i in 2:nrow(df)){
     df$count[i] <- sum(df$extra_col[1:(i-1)] == df$extra_col[i])
}

df <- df[df$count == 0,] #We only want the rows that don't have an identical value above them.
```

Nothing wrong with the old ways for something like this. If you can save yourself some thought, it's probably going to make your day better. And this method extends itself to excel perfectly.